# Table % categorical variable from different subsets

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 15 metrics (columns) from a csv. 1 metric is called `Cancer`

This is what the column in the dataset looks like

```
Cancer:  yes no yes no
```

I would like to create a table with the percentages Cancer Yes No 
But I am making different subsets (e.g filtered dataset 1: agegroup 50-54 and numberrelatives=1, filtered dataset 2: agebirtfirstchild <30, breastdensity:extremely dense) I would like to make 1 table with the percentages cancer yes/no with all the different subsets

example dataset:

```
`cancer = c("yes", "no") 
 agegroup = c("35-39", "40-44") 
 numberrelatives = c("zero", "one") 
 agefirstchild = c("Age < 30", "Age 30 or greater") 
 df = data.frame(cancer, agegroup, numberrelatives, agefirstchild)`
```

Comment: The vectors you supplied for the example dataset have differing number of rows - a data frame can't be made from that. Maybe use the `rep()` function to repeat each vector few times so they all have the same length (e.g. 6, 4, 4, and 4 times)?

Comment: Read up on these functions: `table`, `xtabs`, `prop.table`, `addmargins` and `margin.table`. You can make your question(s) more specific by including a sample of your data using `dput` or by indicating one of the data sets included with R that has data similar to yours. If you actually run the code in your example, you will see that it does not run.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With `dplyr` you can do the following:

```
df %>%
   group_by(agegroup, numberrelatives, agefirstchild) %>%
   summarize(prop_cancer = mean(cancer == 'yes'))
```

Note that the table will be in a long format (but there are ways to make it wide).

Comment: Yes thanks it works partly without the group by, it gives me the summary from 1 dataframe/dataset. But I would like to plot different filtered 
dataframes/filtered datasets in 1 table -> 
    filtered dataset 1   no%
    filtered dataset 2   no%

Comment: Can you also give partial points :)

Comment: You can use the same method for an arbitrary number of variables. E.g. you could do `group_by(agegroup)`, `group_by(numberrelatives)` separately for "main effects" of `agegroup` and `numberrelatives`). By that logic, when you `group_by` more variables simultaneously, you're checking the interactions of the categorical variables you grouped by.

Comment: Yes this indeed does what it needs to do as well. Thanks

Comment: I voted your answer as a solution but someone closed the question because it was already answered :( think it therefore turned gray again

Comment: No worries, the important thing is you got your code working!

Comment: Yes thanks for that. The outcome gives valuable insights :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes thanks it works partly without the group by, it gives me the summary from 1 dataframe/dataset. But I would like to plot different filtered 
dataframes/filtered datasets in 1 table -> 
    filtered dataset 1   no%
    filtered dataset 2   no%

Answer (score -1):

Here are some approaches with base R. But first we need some reproducible data:

```
set.seed(42)
cancer <- sample(c("yes", "no"), 200, replace=TRUE) 
agegroup <- sample(c("35-39", "40-44", "45-49"), 200, replace=TRUE)  
numberrelatives <- sample(c("zero", "one", "2 or more"), 200, replace=TRUE)  
agefirstchild <- sample(c("Age < 30", "Age 30 or greater", "nullipareous"), 200, replace=TRUE) 
dat <- data.frame(cancer, agegroup, numberrelatives, agefirstchild)
```

Now you can create tables:

```
(tbl <- xtabs(~agegroup+cancer, dat))
#         cancer
# agegroup no yes
#    35-39 38  31
#    40-44 38  32
#    45-49 35  26
addmargins(tbl)
#         cancer
# agegroup  no yes Sum
#    35-39  38  31  69
#    40-44  38  32  70
#    45-49  35  26  61
#    Sum   111  89 200
```

Or percentages:

```
options(digits=3)
prop.table(tbl, 1) * 100
#         cancer
# agegroup   no  yes
#    35-39 55.1 44.9
#    40-44 54.3 45.7
#    45-49 57.4 42.6
prop.table(tbl, 2) * 100
#         cancer
# agegroup   no  yes
#    35-39 34.2 34.8
#    40-44 34.2 36.0
#    45-49 31.5 29.2
```

Comment: Works beautiful! It gives great insight in where the problems in the subgroups are. Thank you! Would it be possible to add to the table agegroup + cancer also e.g the column agefirstchild. So you can look at the combination?                                                     agefirstchild   agegroup   no     yes                                                                                      <30                 35-39        34      42

Comment: Yes. For example try `xtabs(agegroup+agefirstchild+cancer, dat)`. This creates a 3-dimensional table. To customize which variables are rows and which are columns, you use `ftable()`.

Comment: I voted your answer as a solution but someone closed the question because it was already answered :( think it therefore turned gray again